# What is the next number in the series: 21, 21, 23, 20, 5, 25, 31, 24,?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

I came across a puzzle from a workbook for primary school students who wish to sit in exams for enrolling to selective high schools, which asks about what is the next number in the series.

> 20. What is the next number in the series?
>
>     21, 21, 23, 20, 5, 25, 31, 24, ?
>
>     (A) 3
>     (B) 10
>     (C) 17
>     (D) 86
>
> <sup>([Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRs6X.jpg))</sup>

I've thought many possibilities but none is satisfactory.

What is the next number?

Comment: I understand the point of questions like this, but I've noticed that they tend to teach math students that sequences have to follow an obvious pattern. On the contrary, there are approximately 800 distinct, mathematically interesting [sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2c2%2c4%2c8%2c16) that feature 1,2,4,8,16 in that order.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins funny that you mention this given this recent question: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89273/circle-divided-by-lines-between-a-blue-dots#89273

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I would expect the answer to be

> A) 3

Because

> If you look at how each term is reached from the last it looks like $\times1,+2,-3,\div4,\times5,+6,-7$ and if we were to continue this it would be $\div8$.
>  $24\div8 = 3$

Comment: Thank you, Adam. I think that's how the sequence was made.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> A) 3

My reasoning

> 21=21*1, 23=21+2, 20=23-3, 5=20/4, 25=5*5, 31=25+6, 24=31-7. Each new term is generated by doing 'something' to the previous term. This something cycles between multiplication, addition, subtraction and division. Also the values used increase by 1. So the next number should be 24/8 = 3. Unfortunately this integer sequence breaks down the next time we need to divide as we have 26/12, which is not integer.

Comment: Nobody said that all the elements in the sequence have to be integers.

Comment: An interesting challenge would be to see if changing the starting number would allow you to continue the sequence for longer before getting a non-integer result.  I suspect that you couldn't get too high because of that pesky divide step.  There might be a proof somewhere that shows that such a sequence would always eventually break...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I wrote a program to check this. It turns out that we cannot get more than 9 steps before reaching a non-integer value. 9 steps occur when we start from $32n-11$, for any $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Could it possibly go for longer by changing the order of operations?  There's 24 different ways of mixing them up, might take a while to try them all with a variety of different starting points.  If we could somehow get a sequence that doesn't terminate so early, it might be worthy of the OEIS...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman great minds think alike! I already did exactly what you suggested and created an OEIS sequence about it. It is still not approved, but it will be A327962. If you start with 27846 and alternate between /,+,-,* you can make 24 terms before you reach a non-integer.

Answer (score -2):

> 3
>  It is a sequence of addition, subtraction, division and multiplication

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. This appears to be correct, however the correct answer has already been posted above.

Comment: Also, you should avoid a one-line answer and explain how you came up with that answer.